# Internet Explorer swallows events

Tags: css, internet-explorer, event-handling, z-index

I got a div containing several clickable, draggable and resizable elements.
I also want these movable elements to disappear behind a partially transparent (background-)image.
It all works nicely on anything but Internet Exploder.

my code (reduced to the bare minimum of what produces the problem) looks like this:

```
<div id="container" style="z-index: 200; position: absolute">
    <div style="position:absolute; width: 20px; height: 80px; background-color: red; opacity: .2"></div>
    <div id="works">not works</div>
</div>
```

I also created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUfp5/11/

as you can see in the console, directly clicking the element will fire the handler but won't if you click at the overlay.

shouldn't the event bubble??

is there any way i can get this to work or does internet exploder yet again ruin it?

**UPDATE:**

*i edited the fiddle to make it work with firefox so the problem can be ovserved in its full scope*

Comment: You new fiddle from the update breaks in Safari (and maybe IE), because a `;` is missing after the parenthesis. Here's a fixed one: http://jsfiddle.net/YBUtg/

Comment: @insertusernamehere seems not to be a problem on anything but safari (which is why i got this habit :), but thank you. i updated the url :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not event bubbling. The problem is that your overlay hides your "not works layer". [CSS `pointer-events` for non SVG elements is not supported in IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events).

When the event reaches `#container` the event target is not `#works`, but your overlay and therefore jQuery does not fire your event.

A solution could be described here: 
http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Essentially he binds the events to the overlay, and handles them by:

1. "hide the overlay"
2. find what element is beneath
3. forward the event to the element beneath;

here is a forked fiddle of your example which implements that. 
http://jsfiddle.net/QY69w/

If your events are such as "mousemove", etc. Maybe it could be necessary to hide your overlay on mousedown and show it only on mouseup (instead of immediately after).

Comment: that must be because `pointer-events` is from the svg spec. do you see any solution to this? (possibly apart from `pointer-events`). all i want is an image "hovering" over some elements which still receive events.

Comment: not really.. easiest would be to put your overlay under your draggable elements and set an opacity on them. The final result will look similar, I guess. You can do this by settting `position: relative` and a `z-index` on them. (like `insertusernamehere`'s answer

Comment: unfortunately that method won't help either. :( i +1'ed you both regardless.

Comment: i will accept your answer since your mention of "non SVG elements" encouraged me to try and implement the overlay image as an <svg><image></svg> which makes `pointer-events` work perfectly in all browsers. thank you (for what it's worth :)

Comment: PS: forget the event forwarding. i had tried that and while it might work for some few elements, it makes internet exploder complain about "not enough memory in stack" if you forward several events to several elements and lag unbearably in other browsers.

Comment: IE8 is for cavemen anyways, actually the whole IE thing is, but oh well... thanks again for your time and effort, both of you.

Answer (score 2):

[Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913761/roman)'s answer is right - +1. You can get the expected behavior by using:

```
position: relative;
```

on the `<div id="works">`. Tested it in IE9 only.

Comment: i cannot confirm this when taking it to my actual code. not even the CSS-`pointer` rule seems to work. besides, the draggables don't like positions to be relative.